# how to present the same view controller after dismissing its once in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I have a `UITabBarController` which has four view controllers.  In every view controller I have a collection view.  In each collection view I have some images.  When I  select an image from the third view controller it opens a web view controller which is not in `UITabBarController`.

In web view controller I have a back button on top with navigation bar. After pressing that back button it's coming back to third view controller.  Again when I select another image in third view controller, it should open the web view controller, but the web view controller didn't appear on simulator instead saying error 1thread,1breakpoint.

Here is my code:

This code is in thirdviewcontroller after selecting the image

```
webViewController = [[AppsWebViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This code is in webviewcontroller after pressing the back button

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I need the webviewcontroller to open every time after selecting any image in any of the four view controllers.

my thirdviewcontroller code:

```
#import "FreqAppsThirdViewController.h"


@interface FreqAppsThirdViewController ()

@end

@implementation FreqAppsThirdViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

icons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"amazon-1.png",@"best_buy.png",@"Carl-Icahn-Lectures-Apple-Gambles-Netflix-and-Threatens-eBay-2.jpg",@"index.jpg",@"Office-Max.jpg", nil];
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
_collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
[_collectionView setDataSource:self];
[_collectionView setDelegate:self];

[_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
[_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[self.view addSubview:_collectionView];

[super viewDidLoad];
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return icons.count;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewdidSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 if (indexPath.row == 0) {


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.amazon.com/"];


    webViewController = [[FreqAppsWebViewController alloc]initWithURL:url andTitle:@"Amazon"];
    [self presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

  } else if (indexPath.row == 1){
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bestbuy.com/"];


    webViewController = [[FreqAppsWebViewController alloc]initWithURL:url andTitle:@"Best Buy"];
    [self presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
  } else if (indexPath.row == 2){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ebay.com"]];
  } else if (indexPath.row == 3){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.walmart.com"]];
  } else if (indexPath.row == 4){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.officemax.com"]];
  }
  // datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // highlight selection
  }

  - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout (UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
   return CGSizeMake(50, 50);
  }

  - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayoutinsetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 20, 50, 20);
  }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

my webviewcontroller code:

```
#import "FreqAppsWebViewController.h"
#import "FreqAppsThirdViewController.h" 
#import "FreqAppsAppDelegate.h"

@interface FreqAppsWebViewController ()

@end

@implementation FreqAppsWebViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url andTitle:(NSString *)string {
if( self = [super init] ) {
    theURL = url;
    theTitle = string;
}
return self;
}

-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
 return [self initWithURL:url andTitle:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
webTitle.title = theTitle;
NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
[webView loadRequest:requestObject];
}

- (IBAction) back:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
webView.delegate = nil;
[webView stopLoading];
}

@end
```

my webviewcontroller.h code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FreqAppsWebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
NSURL *theURL;
NSString *theTitle;
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
IBOutlet UINavigationItem *webTitle;

}

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url;
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url andTitle:(NSString *)string;
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender;
@end
```

my thirdviewcontroller.h code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FreqAppsWebViewController.h"


@interface FreqAppsThirdViewController:UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
{
UICollectionView *_collectionView;
NSArray *icons;
FreqAppsWebViewController *webViewController;

}
```

@end

Comment: You should supply more code

Comment: can you post more code and the complete error? Also when you alloc the webViewController, check if you already have initializate it..this is just an improvement.

Comment: i added more code, so go through it and find my mistake plz

Comment: A huge code dump doesn't really help - you need to provide the specific error message you have received and the line of code where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste the full error message you're getting.

If it is a breakpoint, not an error, as you seem to be indicating, it might just be that you clicked on a the margin of your source and set a breakpoint without realizing it.

To check for breakpoints:

Press Command 7 to display the breakpoint navigator and see if there are any breakpoints set in your code. If there are, you'll an outline starting with the target (the current app) then the source file .m, and then an entry listing a method name and line number, with a symbol that looks like a cross between a right-pointing arrow and a blue sticky note.

If there are breakpoints, select them one at a time and note where they are in your code. Are then in your IBAction method, or the one of the methods in your AppsWebViewController?

Delete each breakpoint by selecting it and pressing the delete key. Then run your program again.

Comment: it is showing breakpoint at @implementation FreqAppsWebViewController. what i need to do\

Comment: i read your comment but how can we delete @implementation from a class.

Comment: What? No. Select the breakpoint in the list of breakpoints, and then press the delete key.